# HTML 5 fonts sizes

Tags: css, html

I want to make website for mobile
How can I make the font sizes stretches with mobile screen's resolutions

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p{font-size:1em;
/* font-size:20px; */
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard 
dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has s
urvived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic  .
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `em` instead of `px`

example:

```
font-size: 1.1em;
```

Comment: I used it but it not worked correctly :(

Comment: @EngMaisa Read some documentation about Responsive Web Design and then use GeekyCenter 's advice :)

Comment: use the all the height and width in %  like   font-size:20%;  in css and also add the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in header

Answer (score 0):

put meta in the header part.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: how can i test it before testing in mobile ?

Comment: I used it also but not working

Comment: Can you share your code, so I can catch your query?

Comment: I edited my question an wrote my code :)

Comment: Can you try below one. I tried that and that's work fine.

choose your font in body.

body{font:normal 100% Calibri}
p{font-size:120%;}